# How to generate pdf after saving data in create view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, dompdf

I'm using barryvdh/dompdf wrapper for printing and saving PDF's, when I try to "Print" after inserting data to database it's not fetching last saved data to PDF.

I have tried fetching data by getting last saved id still no luck.

Print button of Main View:

```
<a href="{!! url('printPDF') !!}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info">Print</a>
```

Controller:

```
 public function printPDF(Request $request)
    {
        $visID = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('id')->first();
        $exi= $visID;
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', compact('exi'));
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

pdfview:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $exi['first_name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $exi['last_name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Getting only "First Name:" and "Last Name:" in print preview.

Comment: you are plucking only id. so `{{ $exi['first_name'] }}` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues that you could potentially improve.  The first is that if you are hoping to get a collection of objects but are only using the method of `first()`, it will just give you a single instance.  Using `pluck` further compounds this, as it won't give you the entire object, but just one field (`id`) in your example code:

```
$visID = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('id')->first();
```

I suggest you change the above to get the full model.  Remove `pluck`, add `latest()` if your db has the `created_at` field to support it:

```
$exi = MyModel::latest()->first();
```

**or**, you were on the right track, and can do it with the orderBy as well (Laravel's `latest()` is just syntactic sugar for the same thing - looks neat):

```
$exi = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Then, instead of:

```
$exi= $visID;
```

You already have the last model within the variable from the query line above.  After passing through to blade, you have all the data within `$exi` and can use object notation you wish:

```
<tr>
     <th>First Name:</th>
     <td>{{ $exi->first_name }}</td>
</tr>
// etc
```

Comment: get() method will retrieve all of the available data but I just want to retrieve last saved data therefore I used pluck() method

Comment: That's fine.  Change `get()` to `first()`.  Not `pluck`.  So `$exi = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();`  Remove the `@foreach` I had.  This query should get you the data you need.  Or to make sure it is the last, if you have a `created_at` field, you can do `->latest()->first();`  I will update my answer to make it more helpful

Comment: Fantastic! it's fetching properly now :)

Answer (score 0):

You just pluck one value and not the array or multi value.

```
Model::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('**column name**','id')->first();
```

Comment: Tried your solution, MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')->first();
still not fetching data.

Comment: I think you have no need pluck . because pluck  geven us  select ->option  value. but your need just simple value. you try it  Model::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

Comment: Right, Watercayman has mentioned, it's solved now btw thanks :)